# fb post to wall function shows syntax error unexpected identifier? But the JS is valid?

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

Using the facebook javascript sdk - I have made this function to post information to the wall of the current facebook user.

But I'm sure this is correct (obviously not) but cannot find the syntax error anywhere.

The error only appears when I click the the post to wall button. Can any one help me understand why the error is coming about?

Thanks
Josh

Please see my full tab app code below.

```
<?php

require 'facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php';

$fb_app_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$fb_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$fb_admins = 'XXXXXXXXX';
$fb_channel_url = '//myapp.co.uk';

$og_title = 'My App';
$og_description = 'This is my app';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fb_app_id,
  'secret' => $fb_secret,
  'cookie' => true
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">

    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="<?php echo $fb_app_id; ?>">
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="<?php echo $fb_admins; ?>">

</head>
<body>

    <a href="#" onclick="fb_publish('<?php echo $fb_app_url; ?>','<?php echo $og_title; ?>','Image URL Here','<?php echo $og_description; ?>'); return false;">Post to wall</a>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script>

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

            FB.init({
                appId      : '<?php echo $fb_app_id; ?>', // App ID
                channelUrl : '<?php echo $fb_channel_url; ?>',
                status     : true, // check login status
                cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
            });

            FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(true);

        };

        function fb_publish(link,title,image,description) {
            var obj = {
              method: 'feed',
              link: link,
              picture: image,
              name: title,
              caption: 'facebook.com&#47;mypage',
              description: description
            };
            function callback(response) {

            }
            FB.ui(obj, callback);
        }

        /*****  load SDK  *****/
        (function(d){
             var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
             ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        }(document));

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept on trying figure out my problem and in the I got the post wall function to work.

The reason for the unexpected identifier was because of my php string. Not escaping things properly.

I fixed the problem with some help here: [How to echo php string safely in a java script onclick identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647160/how-to-echo-php-string-safely-in-a-java-script-onclick-identifier)

Also note when wanting to use the post to wall function, you need to allow the access to the domain using App Domains. (see all my setting below)

[image]