# How to echo php string safely in a java script onclick identifier

Tags: php, javascript

Please don't mark this as duplicate as I can't find a working solution on the very similar questions. None of them seem to fix my specific string.

I have this PHP variable...

```
<?php

   $og_description = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus hendrerit cursus mi, Nullam condi\'mentum posuere odio sed cursus.. Proin posue\'re fermentum, ligula vel lacinia sollicitudin, libero quam ultrices quam, quis tristique orci... enim a justo!'

?>
```

The string above has exactly the same special characters I am using.

I am then trying to echo it into this onclick identifier. Obviously `<?php echo $og_description; ?>` is not going to work on its own.

```
<a href="#" onclick="fb_publish('<?php echo $fb_app_url; ?>','<?php echo $og_title; ?>','images/icon.png','<?php echo $og_description; ?>'); return false;">Post to wall</a>
```

I have tried these...

```
echo htmlspecialchars($og_description);
echo json_encode($og_description);
```

and a few others but nothing seemed to fix my string into a format that would not break the identifier array.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks
Josh

Comment: use echo urlencode($og_description) instead and decode it using decodeURIcomponent of javascript in your js function

Comment: This should work.
Can you copy the HTML code of the page to see what's going on there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onclick="fb_publish(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($string), ENT_COMPAT); ?>)"
```

You need to *both* escape/encode it to be valid Javascript syntax and *then* escape/encode it to be a valid HTML attribute.

Comment: Thanks @deceze this worked great for this particular string. Again thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend using inline JavaScript, but here's one way to do it:

```
$anchor_fmt = '<a href="#" onclick="fb_publish.apply(window, %s);return false;">Post to wall</a>';
$js_args = array(
    $fb_app_url, 
    $og_title, 
    'images/icon.png', 
    $og_description
);
echo sprintf($anchor_fmt, 
   htmlspecialchars(json_encode($js_args), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
);
```

It uses `json_encode()` to form an array that's passed to the JavaScript function using `.apply()`. In the end you need to make sure that the resulting string is still valid in HTML context.

Btw, it could be written completely in one line, but I've split it up for readability.

Comment: Thanks jack for taking the time to give this answer. I started at the top and deceze option fixed my problem. But I like the way you've put all the php vars into an array. Not sure how apply(window, %s) does anything? I will test this on my next 'post to wall' function using this method.

Comment: @Joshc If you started at the top you would have seen this answer first. Regardless, whatever works for you is important of course :)

Answer (score 0):

You could assign to js variables first:

```
<script>
var fb_app_url = <?php echo json_encode($fb_app_url); ?>;
var og_title = <?php echo json_encode($og_title); ?>;
var og_description = <?php echo json_encode($og_description); ?>;
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="fb_publish(fb_app_url,og_title,'images/icon.png',og_description); return false;">Post to wall</a>
```